# Disable Swipe to dismiss on ONLY ONE activity

Tags: wear-os, swipe-gesture

I have a fragment activity and I want to disable the swipe to dismiss feature on this, and only this, activity.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

on my manifest in the activity I want to disable the swipe to dismiss I've added this:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ACTIVITYNAME"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Wearable.Modal"/>
```